# Rewriting a product of cosines of multiple angles in terms of a product of cosines of a single angle

Tags: trigonometry, induction

I know that

$$\sin^2(2^n x) = 4^n\sin^2(x)\left(\prod_{j=1}^n \cos(2^{n-j}x)\right)^2$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am trying to derive an expression for $\sin^2(2^n x)$ in terms of only sines and cosines that are functions of $x$ only (i.e. without multiple-angles).

How can I rewrite $$\prod_{j=1}^n \cos(2^{n-j}x) = \cos(x)\cos(2x)\cdots\cos(2^{n-1}x)$$
in terms of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ only?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosines of multiple angles are polynomial in the cosine of the angle, these are the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). Squares of sines in multiple angles are polynomial in the sine squared of the angle, these are the [spread polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Spread_polynomials).